# What is the best way to parse message with various fields, and then run commands based on the fields?

Tags: c, parsing, struct, tree

So right now I have a structure defined that looks like this:

```
typedef struct rec_msg {
    uint8_t unit[4];
    uint8_t subdevice[4];
    uint8_t command[4];
    uint16_t  data[3];
    uint16_t  msg_id[1];
} rec_msg;
```

...and I want to read the character arrays in the struct and then run a command based on them. Right now I'm doing it like this, and it just seems like there would be a much cleaner way to do it.

```
 if (strncmp((const char *)message->unit, "blah", 3) == 0)
  {
    if (strncmp((const char *)message->subdevice, "syr", 3) == 0) 
    {
      if (strncmp((const char *)message->command, "rem", 3) == 0)
      {
        // run some command
      }
      else if (strncmp((const char *)message->command, "dis", 3) == 0)
      {
        // run some command
      }
      else
      {
        DEBUG_PRINT("Message contains an improper command name");
      }
    }
    else if (strncmp((const char *)message->subdevice, "rot", 3) == 0)
    {
      if (strncmp((const char *)message->command, "rem", 3) == 0)
      {
        // run some command
      }
      else if (strncmp((const char *)message->command, "dis", 3) == 0) 
      {
        // run some command
      }
      else
      {
        DEBUG_PRINT("Message contains an improper command name");
      }
    }
    else
    {
      DEBUG_PRINT("Message contains an improper subdevice name");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    DEBUG_PRINT("Message contains the wrong unit name");
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _cleaner_? A Macro?

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, it seems a bit ridiculous to basically create a giant if/else if tree.

Comment: The way would be to first do parsing, fill some structure with the parsed command/data, then switch/case on the command and perform whatever.

Comment: Your options are limited when you need to branch based on the contents of strings.  Where there are only certain valid strings, as here, it perhaps makes more sense to replace them numeric codes, and potentially to pre-validate those.  That opens several possibilities.

Comment: There are also several possible variations on creating a table or tables of function pointers and computing which one to use unconditionally.  Whether these should be considered better than what you're doing now is a context-dependent question of style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than explicit code for a general question, break the task into steps.  Pseudo-code follows.

For each of the 3 sets of strings, convert the matching text to a number.  Suggest an array of strings with a corresponding enumeration.  (2 shown below)

```
enum unit_index {
  unit_blah,
  unit_N
};

const char *unit_string[unit_N] = {
  "blah"
};

enum subdevice_index {
  subdevice_syr,
  subdevice_rot,
  subdevice_N
};

const char *subdevice_string[subdevice_N] = {
  "syr"
  "rot"
};
```

Look up the matching index

```
unit_index unit = find_index(message->unit, unit_string, unit_N);
if (unit >= unit_N) {
  DEBUG_PRINT("Message contains the wrong unit name");
  return FAIL;
}

subdevice_index subdevice = find_index(message->subdevice, subdevice_string, subdevice_N);
if (subdevice >= subdevice_N) {
  DEBUG_PRINT("Message contains the wrong subdevice name");
  return FAIL;
}

// similar for command
```

Now code has 3 indexes corresponding to the 3 text fields.

Create table of indexes and corresponding command

```
typedef struct {
  enum unit_index       unit;
  enum subdevice_index  subdevice;
  enum command_index    command;
  int (*func)();
} index2func;

index2func[] = {
  { unit_blah, subdevice_syr, command_dis, command_blah_syr_dis },
  { unit_blah, subdevice_rot, command_dis, command_blah_rot_dis },
  ...
  { unit_blah, subdevice_rpt, command_rem, command_blah_rot_rem }
};
```

Walk the table for a matching set of indexes and execute command.

Comment: Thanks so much! Perfect answer!